# What is relation between Angular, Angular-CLI, Angular-seed & Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-cli, angular-seed

I am working on Angular 2 Project.
Here I am confused, how those CLI, Seed & Ionic related to Angular.
Those are developed in the Angular platform.

CLI, Seed & Ionic are sub-frameworks of Angular???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/) is a command line interface to scaffold and build angular apps using nodejs style (commonJs) modules. Not only it provides you scalable project structure, instead it handles all common tedious tasks for you out of the box. Angular CLI create Angular Apps
[Angular Seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) project is an application skeleton for a typical AngularJS (Not for Angular, Angular CLI is for Angular Apps) web app. You can use it to quickly bootstrap your angularjs webapp projects and dev environment for these projects. Angular Seed is an angularjs application.
[Ionic Framework](https://ionicframework.com/) is an ultimate open source software development kit (SDK), used for developing hybrid mobile applications with JavaScript (angularjs & Angular rigth now), CSS and HTML5. Ionic mainly focused on the look, feel and UI interactions of an app. Ionic use Angular for building mobiles apps. 
Hope I help!

Answer (score 0):

CLI is short for command line interface, which lets you execute certain commands of framework from your command line. Example ng serve would host your project on localhost.

Seed is a startup project that you just get and can start developing, you can think of it as a skeleton. Then you just develop over the skeleton what you want.